# Populating data in a li tag dynamically using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm working on an application whereby I have data in a Javascript 
object which I have pulled from the backend. The data is in 2 separate objects. I'm trying to iterate through each object and populate in the DOM dynamically, the 1st array populates well but the 2nd array isn't working.

**Objects from the browser console**

```
//1st Object
const subject = {
      0: "Mathematics",
      1: "English",
      2: "Swahili",
      3: "Science"
};

//2nd Object
const value = {
      0: "90%",
      1: "70%",
      2: "50%",
      3: "85%"
};
```

**My logic**

```
//Logic to loop through 1st Object
 $("#packageBenefits ul li");
    $.each(subject, function (key, value) { 
        $details.eq(key).text(value);
});

//Logic to loop through 2nd object
$('#packageBenefits ul li >span').each(function(index) {
      $(this).html(value[index]);
});
```

**Markup**

```
 <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">All subjects</div>
      <div class="card-body" id="packageBenefits">
        <ul>
          <li> Subject <span> </span> </li>
          <li> Subject <span> </span> </li>
          <li> Subject <span> </span> </li>
          <li> Subject <span> </span> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It *does* work. Whatever the problem was, it isn't exposed by your question. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Quentin  I have re framed the question about the actual problem am facing,,

Comment: Why didn't you keep the live demo?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first loop replaces the contents of the `<li>` elements with new text. This replaces the entire contents of the `<li>` elements.

The second loop loops over all the `<span>` elements inside the `<li>` elements, but **there aren't any** because the first loop just replaced them.

You could put another `<span>` inside the `<li>` and loop over the second one for the first loop and the first one for the second, or write a single loop that concatenates the strings from the two objects.